# How to get rid of the (More Links...) link on lists in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: list

I have a list of 5 items. The view settings are set so that the Item Limit is 20. I would like the eliminate the (More Links...) link under the list when the web part is on the page. I also tried setting the Toolbar properties to No Toolbar. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no OOB solution for this. You would probably need to use JavaScript/Jquery and hide the (More Links..) anchor tag (ID=onetidMoreFavs).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely there is not Out-Of-Box method to remove the (more links...) hyperlink from the summary view. However you can create new custom view and set item limit to 5 or any number of you choice [defaul number if items is 30].

I hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use Sharepoint Designer 2010.  Edit the page in Advanced mode (right click and choose edit in advanced mode) then click on the "(more links)" and delete.  You can also do this for column headers of lists and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem. Can't you just "Edit current view" in the web part tool bar then under Item Limit type in 5 and select "Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount."

Works fine on my 2010 VM.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **SharePoint Designer**, and switch to Code View.

Locate the web part and the following line of code inside the  block and remove it:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="MoreAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,morelinks_ellipses)" />
```

Save and refresh your browser. No more (More links...) link.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found.  The **"More Links..."** shows when the list that you are referencing has more records in it than the applied views **"Item Limit"** Number of items to display count.

Example: I have link list "References"  has 20 items.

- I add a web part on a page that uses "References"   I apply a summary
  view.
- I do not see "**More Links...**"
- I add an item to References and now "**More Links...**" appears.

**"Edit the Web Part"**

- "Edit the current view"
- Change the "Item Limit" - Number of items to display to 21 or more
- Choose OK.

I do not see **"More Links..."**

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if theres a simple reason but why dont you just create a standard list with hyperlink column, when you display this in a webpart the "More Links" feature isnt part of a standard list feature

Answer (score -2):

- go to edit page.
- modify shared web part.
- select appearance and choose the pixels for height and width as 800.

Comment: This won't hide the 'More Links...' element, it will just resize the window of the web part.